# SurfaceHolder.setType is deprecated... But required?

Tags: android, surfaceholder

> void android.view.SurfaceHolder.setType(int type)
>
> public abstract void setType (int type)  Since: API Level 1
>
> This method is deprecated. this is ignored, this value is set
>   automatically when needed.
>
> Sets the surface's type.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html

It says it's set automatically but, without it my video doesn't play. What's going on here? Is there something that replaces it? I'm having a time getting video to play correctly on Android.

Comment: how are you playing your video? post some code.

Comment: The value is set automatically when needed. That is what document says for android. But if it is less than honeycomb then you should set it as shown in below replies

Comment: Deprecated .Still it will work .

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The trick is in knowing *when* it was deprecated, which is kind of hard to determine from my experience. The documentation is always current for the latest API available, but you are probably not running this app on the latest API, if I had to guess. So you still have to use this method (typically with PUSH_BUFFERS) to make it work on older platforms.

EDIT: it was deprecated in Android 3.0, which the docs now reflect.
So we can use it like following:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    getHolder().setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
```

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes that would make since. I wish they would say when. I didn't realize the doc was the latest while developing in Eclipse for 2.2

Comment: Also, if you look at the source code for Android's `VideoView` you can see that it does this:

`getHolder().setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);`

Comment: its making me wait :) 4 minutes.

Comment: According to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html, this is a deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0; please reflect this fact in your post. Thanks.

Comment: @lyricsboy I still get a deprecation warning even when I put this call inside of the SDK_INT conditional. The only option Eclipse gives me to to suppress "deprecation" for the entire method I am in. Is there not a way to suppress the warning only for this line?

Comment: Until Java 8 (which is not relevant for Android), annotations can only be used on declarations of classes, variables, methods, etc. If you want to avoid applying that deprecation suppression too broadly, you can extract the questionable code into its own method and mark that method with `@SuppressWarnings`.

Comment: and what do we do if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) ????????????

Comment: @user3051067 wondering the same thing if we need to use >= because the API was deprecated in that API level.

Comment: For 3.0 (honeycomb) and higher, you do not need to call this method at all. As the docs state, it is ignored and set automatically.

Comment: Honestly this is worst suggestion IMHO, when its said deprecated , its deprecated , no matter you use it for which SDK and API level, also its clearly stated that it will be ignored for higher SDKs , so even in that case you don't have to check the SDK.