# How to solve SurfaceHolder.setType deprecated ? Is there any other method?

Tags: android, camera, surfaceholder

What is used in place of `surfaceholder.settype` ?

```
PreviewHolder = CameraPreview.getHolder();
       PreviewHolder.addCallback(this);
       if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)

        PreviewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For 3.0 (honeycomb) and higher, you do not need to call this method at all. As the docs state, it is ignored and set automatically. [SurfaceHolder.setType is deprecated… But required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439186/surfaceholder-settype-is-deprecated-but-required)